# Zend Mail Imap: Fetch Body of Multipart?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-mail

I have a small "problem" with Zend_Mail_Storage_Imap and MultiPart Mails.

> ContentType: multipart/alternative;
>   boundary=f46d043bd88a9f5d9004c87d2ad3

Part 1 has the Text of the Message, but with headers inside the content, so when i try

```
$part->getContent();
```

> --f46d043bd88a9f5d9004c87d2ad3 Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8 Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
>
> Hallo

is the result, how to extract the header information now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of:

```
$part->getContent();
```

do:

```
$part->getHeader();
```

to get Headers or if you want ONLY content then:

try:

```
while ($part->isMultipart()) {
    $part = $message->getPart(1);
}
```

or

```
$message = $mail->getMessage($messageNum);
```

for content without body.

If issue persists, check your mail on mail client's like Gmail. Sometimes, we add header information twice (accidentally) whilst sending the mail.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: :-) The problem is now the first part ;)

Comment: Oh! I see... Hmmm.... Superman on the move! Gimme a moment, I will replicate, research, edit the current answer and write what you asked for... zwooooosh!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Thats still not the solution: Part(1) is the text part, but how to identify it as text part (i think you can have X Parts).

Comment: You can indeed have x number of parts. However, question is, have you tried the solution above? Also, when the question is 'how to identify' then it is through `$this->getContentType()`

Comment: Thanks enough inspiration now :-)